# Passing variable through lambda into functions Tkinter

Tags: python, class, lambda, callback, tkinter

My problem with the following code is passing 'i' (just a simple range of numbers but changes according to number_boxes) through lambda to callback in order to have seperate functionality of each box created.

I have tried reading tutorials and attempted various things in my code but it either doesn't work or I get errors 'lambda() requires only 2 arguments, 3 given' etc. I believe I would need to make 'i' a list but I still get this particular error..

I have commented on the code where the problems arise. I need to return the values inside each box as well as overwrite the text.

Thank you.

```
self.clicked = [] # In my __init__ definition
self.numbers = [StringVar() for i in xrange(self.number_boxes) ]   # Create Stringvar for each box

for i in xrange(self.number_boxes): # For each number, create a box

        self.clicked.append(False) # Not clicked in yet
        self.box.append(Entry(self.frame_table,bg='white',borderwidth=0, width=10, justify="center", textvariable=self.numbers[i], fg='grey')) # Textvariable where I enter a value to get after, need to do for each box (use box[i] but cannot for append)
        self.box[i].grid(row=row_list,column=column+i, sticky='nsew', padx=1, pady=1) 
        self.box[i].insert(0, "Value %g" % float(i+1))
        self.box[i].bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, index=i : self.callback(event, index)) # Need to pass the 'i's' to callback but having lambda difficulties

for i in self.numbers: 
        i.trace('w',lambda index=i: self.numberwritten(index) ) # Need for each box again here

def numberwritten(self, index): # A way of combining numberwritten and callback?
    po = self.box[index].get() # Get the values in each box
    print po

def callback(self, event, index):
        if (self.clicked[index] == False): # When clicked in box, overwrite default text with value and change colour to black, not grey
            self.box[index].delete(0, END)
            self.box[index].config(fg='black')
                self.clicked[index] = True
```

UPDATE: Current problem: Need to pass all values of 'i' to callback and not just one but how to put list into lambda?

Error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python26\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
TypeError: lambda() takes at most 1 argument (3 given)
```

Comment: I don't understand line `po = box[i].get()`: shouldn't it be `po = self.box[i].get()` instead ? I don't understand `lambda i: self.numberwritten(n)` either: where does `n` come from ?

Comment: Yep sorry, I used the old version of code. Code edited.

Comment: paste the full traceback

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, I've included all that linked to the numberwritten function.

Comment: @user2063: before TypeError: ... line there should be many more lines in the output that trace the stack from where the error occurred to the top level. The first line is: `Traceback (most recent call):`. All these line together are called `traceback`.

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Python26\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1410, in __call__ return self.func(*args)

Comment: What is it you are really trying to accomplish? Do you really need a callback every time each entry is changed? For what purpose? Is it for input validation? If so, there are better ways to do input validations on entry widgets.

Comment: I would like to have 'n' entry boxes created each with a default grey text specifying it's value number. Then upon clicking it, I want to be able to change the text (now black) and be able to assign each value to a variable. Value1 = a, Value2 = b. The problem is that the number of value is random and I therefore cannot do a lambda of 4 values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is very close, however this line:

```
self.box[i].bind("<Button-1>", lambda self, event,i : self.callback(event, data))
```

should be

```
self.box[i].bind("<Button-1>", lambda event, index=i: self.callback(event, index))
```

The object `index` is just an arbitrary label to which we assign the value of `i`. Note that Python throws an error if we pass `i`, rather than a variable name. And we don't need to pass `self`; it is passed implicitly by its use in the function call: `self.callback()`.

My only other comment is that you should turn `clicked` into a list, so that you can keep track of which objects the user selects. You can form this exactly the way `box` is formed. Good luck.

---

Here are some tips on turning `clicked` into a list, since I think this is current issue you are having. *Edit:* Changed several lines per J.F. Sebastian's comments.

```
# Create an empty list based on the number of boxes created 
# above. This could go in your class's __init__ function, 
# or it could be declared globally, depending on the scope
# of self.box and the loop which determines its length.
self.clicked = ([False] * len(self.box))

# Finally, in your callback, check one member of the list,
# depending on which box was clicked.
def cb(self, event, index):
    if not self.clicked[index]:
        self.box[index].delete(0, END)
        self.box[index].config(fg='black')
        self.clicked[index] = True
    # Print the value of each of the widgets stored in the box list.
    for i, j in enumerate(self.box):
        print("%ith element: %s" % (i, j.get()))
```

Comment: This work but the problem is my loop as index would have to be a list to contain all values of i no? I also don't understand how I could make clicked a list since it's not a numerical one. Sorry to be such a beginner in these things!

Comment: Clicked is a bool object and cannot use append. I'm struggling on getting the final points to my callback function and generally sorting my code out.

Comment: Have updated code as it stands currently. Only able to pass index=0 to callback and still wondering whether it's possible to merge numberwritten and callback to write in and read the values in boxes?

Comment: Regarding lists - they can have any type you want in them, so just use `clicked = []` to make an empty list, then `clicked.append(False)`.

Comment: I have changed my code above, I am still however getting a lambda error. Really confused why it isn't working.

Comment: I believe it may be coming from the def numberwritten but I've used a similar approach with index=i yet it doesn't work?

Comment: Right. If `numberwritten()` and the `for i in self.numbers:` loop are for debugging, then I would comment them out for now. You could print each item in `box[]` each time any one of them is clicked - this would go in `callback()` as well. I'll update my answer.

Comment: I have tested this and it works except it'll print the default text and when I begin to edit the boxes, it again crops up with the lambda error. Would I have to change my textvariable in the original entry box creation?

Comment: you could use: `self.clicked = [False] * len(self.box)` and `if not self.clicked[index]:` syntax instead.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian I should realized `if not self.clicked[index]:` as the more Pythonic syntax but I would not have thought of your suggestion. Thank you! I will edit my answer.

Comment: you forgot to remove for `clicked.append(False)` loop

Answer (score 0):

**updated**:
it seems your lambda is completly superflous. Remove it altogether.

try:

```
self.box[i].bind("<Button-1>",self.callback)
```

instead of:

```
lambda self, event, i: self.callback(event, i)
```

---

update:

While i was typing my answer you seemd to have worsened the situation, maybe
a little clarification of the lambda-idiom would help you more then my solution
above. ;-)

lambda-functions are also known as anonymous-function, for they don't need to
have a name.

compare the following examples:

```
>>>ulist = 'a1 s3 d2 f4 k6 w9'.split()

def normal_sort(L,R):
    result = int(L[1]) - int(R[1])
    return result

>>> sorted(ulist, normal_sort)
['a1', 'd2', 's3', 'f4', 'k6', 'w9']
```

the same as a lambda-function:

```
sorted(ulist, lambda L, R: int(L[1])-int(R[1]))
['a1', 'd2', 's3', 'f4', 'k6', 'w9']
```

The lambda-function has

1. no name
2. no argument parenthesis
3. no return statement, because the evaluation of it's single statement gets passed back as the return value.

You may name a lambda-function by assigning it to a name:

```
lambda_sort = lambda L, R: int(L[1])-int(R[1])
```

but then it may be already useful to switch to a normal function.

Comment: This doesn't work, it still gives me an error with the number of arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the update (I was using an example I found to try and make my code clear, obviously not!). It still however doesn't seem to work and it's really confusing me! I have changed my code back..!

Comment: i dont know which and how many arguments StringVar.trace is supposed to have, but my guess is: ONE and this one should be a string or at least somethig convertible to a string, therefore kill your lambda construct there also

Comment: @DonQuestion: the trace callback takes 3 arguments:, _name1_, _name2_, and _op_. the first is the name of the variable, the second is an index into the variable if it is an array (which I don't think tkinter supports), and the third will be "read", "write", or "unset", depending on which event caused the callback to be called.

Comment: ahh, ok - i'm not a vivid tcl/tk user - this whole "everything is a string" just doesn't appeal to me.